# Error when implementing CacheBuilder using latest guava library (implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre)

Tags: android, caching, guava

Recently I have upgraded the Guava library to `28.2-jre` (implementation `com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre`) after that I cannot use `CacheBuilder` to create database cache. Previously it was working fine with older library. Any idea?. Crash logs are below.

```
--------- beginning of crash
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.base.Suppliers$SupplierOfInstance
        at com.google.common.base.Suppliers.ofInstance(Suppliers.java:268)
        at com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.<clinit>(CacheBuilder.java:168)
        at com.trimble.ag.amaethon.equipment.provider.pub.client.EquipmentClientImplementCache.<init>(EquipmentClientImplementCache.java:65)
        at com.trimble.ag.amaethon.equipment.provider.pub.client.EquipmentClient.<init>(EquipmentClient.java:340)
        at com.trimble.ag.amaethon.equipment.provider.pub.client.EquipmentClient.<init>(EquipmentClient.java:286)
        at com.trimble.sns.equipment.provider.client.EquipmentClient.<init>(EquipmentClient.java:50)
        at com.trimble.sns.equipment.provider.client.EquipmentClient.getInstance(EquipmentClient.java:60)
        at com.trimble.sns.DurangoApplication.onCreate(DurangoApplication.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4712)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your stacktrace you're on Android, so please use different artefact: [guava-28.2-android](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/28.2-android).

More about using Guava on Android on [this Wiki page](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Android).